# Create array in object from object javascript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I've got an object that looks like this:

```
message = {
    date: "12-12-12"                                    
    time: "12:05:10",                                   
    name: "Wence",                              
    message: "hey man how are u doing?"
}
```

Now, I want to create a new object which will look like this:

```
var messages = {"Wence":["hey man how are u doing?","Thanks. I'm fine too.", "are you up for a game of pokémon?"], "Bas":["Hey! Doing fine. How about you?","sure"]}
```

After doing so, I need to loop trough the object and filter on message by person. I need to be able to show for instance if "Wence" or "Bas" sent any pictures in their message (the value in the array is 1 message). I guess this is the best way to do so, but I'm open for any suggestions.

Any help is much appriciated.

Comment: What have you tried? What are you having trouble with? What do you mean by "inherit the messages"? You need to be able to show if they sent any pictures - what is that supposed to mean? What's the best way to do what? Please clarify your post.

Comment: Thanks for editing your question, but there are still points I'm unclear on. Why do you need to loop through the object and filter by person? The messages are already sorted by person (person name as key and messages in an array as values). What do you mean by "the value in the array is 1 message"? Do you mean when the array has exactly 1 message in it (length 1)?

Comment: Yes, but right now I'm looking for a way to filter and analyse the messages per person/username and when calling on the object at once the messages get cluttered.

I'm sorry if it's still a bit unclear. I meant that every array element 'one' message contains.

Comment: I've created a fiddle to demonstrate if it's still a bit unclear. I've used the answer of @tastySpaceApple but as you can see it's not 100% working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this function:

```
function getMessagesByPerson(obj) {
    var data = {}, item;
    for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
         item = obj[i];

         if (!data.hasOwnProperty(item.name)) {
        data[obj.name] = [];
        }

         data[obj.name].push(obj.message);
    }
    return data;
}
```

This will return exactly your wanted output.

Answer (score 1):

You'd first want to create an empty object to serve as a table:

```
var messages = {} //creates a new empty object
```

You'll than have to initialize the list for each user:

```
messages["Wence"] = [] //initialize Wence's messages to an empty list.
```

And then, when you need to, you can add to this list - as you would to any list:

```
messages["Wence"].push("how are you?")
```

And, when you need to, you can loop through it. If you'd want to loop through each user's messages, you'd want to have a nested loop like this:

```
for(var username in messages){
   for(var i=0, len = messages[username].length; i<len; i++){
       var msg = messages[username][i]
  }
}
```

Comment: Good thinking, thanks. I've tried it out but it seems there's still a bit of a bug. My code returns not one object of a lot of them.